# Number of 3-loop diagrams for 3-vertex correction

Tags: quantum-field-theory, field-theory, feynman-diagrams, quantum-gravity

How would I determine the number of three-loop diagrams that are irreducible for the 3-vertex interaction of, lets say, a graviton where the internal exchange is **only** a scalar particle. I am sure there is an easy combinitorics method of doing this, but nothing is coming to mind at the moment.

For example in this paper, [The Ultraviolet Behavior of Einstein Gravity](https://inspirehep.net/literature/216624), there were able to find that the two-loop corrections to the graviton three-vertex has only 14 diagrams in total (and then reduce them down to six by a few arguments that need to be computed but that's a side note). However, I am not sure how they came about those 14 diagrams, or knowing there are 14. (As a side note that may or may not be relevant, technically in the cited paper's calculations, the internal lines of the diagrams are a combination of ghosts + gravitons. So every internal line is really two particles).

My bottom-line question is then, how do I determine the number of diagrams that would contribute to a three-loop calculation of the 3-vertex?

Any kind of suggestions are helpful.

Comment: Comments to the post (v1): 1. Which page mentions the 14 diagrams?...Wait, I found it: Fig.3 & Fig.4 on p.725. 2. Consider to include action for clarity. 3. Consider to restrict to 1PI diagrams.